# Why this ANTLR grammar does not return the proper type?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm working on an example grammar for a vary basic language which has instructions like the following:

```
i8 my_variable_1_8
i16 my_second_variable_2_something_else
i32 another_variable
i4 forth
i8 last_one_1
void empty
void empty_for_the_2_time
```

Just to be clear, the variable name can contain any letter, number, underscore and the dot in any order. ATM I'm not interested in case like ```....variable_name....` so let's accept them :)

The PoC grammar I currently using is in the paragraph below:

```
grammar example;

prog:   (expr NEWLINE)+;

expr    : instr
    ;

instr     : type WORD
      ; 

type    : 'i' NUMBER
    | 'void'
        ;

NUMBER  : ('-')* ([0-9])+
    ;

WORD :  (LETTER|'_'|'.'|[0-9])+
     ;

LETTER   : ([a-z]|[A-Z]) ;

NEWLINE  : [\r\n]+ ;

WS: [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

The example file I'm trying to parse is

```
i32 i_cannot_parse_this_1_as_i_want
void hello
```

The output is

```
➜  grammar antlr4 -no-listener example.g4 && javac *.java && grun example prog -tokens example.txt
[@0,0:2='i32',<WORD>,1:0]
[@1,4:34='i_cannot_parse_this_1_as_i_want',<WORD>,1:4]
[@2,35:35='\n',<NEWLINE>,1:35]
[@3,36:39='void',<'void'>,2:0]
[@4,41:45='hello',<WORD>,2:5]
[@5,48:47='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:0]
line 1:0 mismatched input 'i32' expecting {'i', 'void'}
➜  grammar
```

As you can see the `i32` is considered to be a `WORD` instead of a type. There must something I'm missing about the priorities but I cannot understand it.

Finally, I'd like to say that I create the parser rule `type` because at runtime, once I override the `visitInstr` method I would like to be able to do something like `ctx.type().NUMBER()`.

**EDIT 1**

Suppose that now as a type I want to introduce an array `my_variable = [ 8 * i32 ]`, how would solve this situation. Would you just add something like:

```
TYPE
        : 'i' NUMBER
        | '[' NUMBER '*' TYPE ']'
        ;
```

Using a visit method inside my visitor can easily access to `NUMBER` and `TYPE`. I was thinking to use `ctx.type().getToken()`

Is there a better way to achieve that? Please consider that I'd like to add other more complex types.

Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: the command with `-tokens` will only output lexer rules (tokens), not parser rules. Your `type` is a parser rule so will never be a part of the `-tokens` output.

The literal tokens inside your parser rule `type`:

```
type : 'i' NUMBER
     | 'void'
     ;
```

are really translated as lexer rules, making your lexer look like this:

```
T__0     : 'i';
T__1     : 'void';
NUMBER   : ('-')* ([0-9])+;
WORD     : (LETTER|'_'|'.'|[0-9])+;
LETTER   : ([a-z]|[A-Z]);
NEWLINE  : [\r\n]+;
WS       : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip; // NOTE: remove the \n\r from this class since it is already matched by NEWLINE
```

If you now feed the lexer the input `i32`, it will create a single `WORD` token. It will not create the two tokens `T__0` (`i`) and `NUMBER` (`32`), because the lexer tries to make the longest match for the given input. That is just how it works.

Also, by making `type` a parser rule, you are allowing input like `i    32` (an `i` with spaces in between) to be matched as a `type`. In other words: don't create `type` in your parser, but make it a lexer rule instead and make sure it is defined *before* the `WORD` rule:

```
type : TYPE
     | VOID
     ;

VOID     : 'void';
TYPE     : 'i' NUMBER;
NUMBER   : '-'* [0-9]+;
WORD     : [a-zA-Z_.0-9]+;
NEWLINE  : [\r\n]+;
WS       : [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

This will cause `i32` to be matched as a `TYPE` and not a `WORD`. If you also want `i32` to be matched as a `WORD` in some cases (e.g. the input `i32 i32` is also valid), do something like this:

```
instr : type word
      ;

word  : WORD
      | type
      ;

type  : TYPE
      | VOID
      ;
```

Lastly, you're allowing `NUMBER` to have zero or more `-` signs in front of it, but you probably don't want `i-32` to be matched as a `TYPE` token, right? Best remove the `-` sign, and match it in a parser rule:

```
expr : instr
     | MINUS expr
     | NUMBER
     | WORD
     | ...
     ;
...
MINUS    : '-';
...
NUMBER   : [0-9]+;
...
```

A more complex type, like `[ 8 * i32 ]` would be more appropriate as parser rule:

```
type
 : TYPE                    #simpleType
 | VOID                    #voidType
 | '[' NUMBER '*' TYPE ']' #arrayType
 ;
```

The `#...` parts at the end of the alternatives are called [rule element labels](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#rule-element-labels).

Comment: Excellent answer! It solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry but how do I access to the number 32 of the type now? I think something like ctx.type(0).TYPE().NUMBER().. Thanks

Comment: You don't :). Once it becomes a single token, you cannot extract a part of that. You could keep a dictionary with type-mappings in your visitor `{ "i32": 32, "i16": 16, ... }`, or make the types more specific in your lexer: `I32 : 'i32';` so that resolving it in a listener or visitor is more straight forward.

Comment: But glueing these types inside a parser rule is really not the way to go!

Comment: OK, so I think I find a way inside my visitor to differentiate the type and get the size.

Comment: I have just updated the final part of the question.. sorry I didn't add it yesterday